# Can I create MSDTC Transaction in PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using Powershell 4 to do some deployment tasks including running a number of sql files into a database server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn464259.aspx

I have found the above cmdlets for MSDTC and I can see one for creating a transaction, rollback and commit.  However, I cant find them and I assume its because we are not running Windows 8 and/or Server 2012 R2.

Is there a way that I can create a transaction scope using MSDTC so I can execute all of my scripts knowing that if any of them fail, that they will all roll back?

We are running Windows 7 & Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I believe that while in transaction scope MSDTC will be used automatically when using commands with two or more connection strings pointing to different servers. If MSDTC is not configured you would get an error when using transaction scope across servers.

Comment: @lrb That is exactly what I want to do.  I have done this a number of times in .net but never in Powershell.  MSDTC is configured on my dev box and on the server as we use distributed transactions across multiple WCF services.  I just don't know how to do this within the context of Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should try using PowerShell with MSDTC directly in the way that you are thinking. Instead I would just use plain old SQL `TRANSACTION` statements: `BEGIN` `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK`...

I think what you really are looking for is the SQL statement `BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION`

See: [MSDN: BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188386.aspx)

This will use MSDTC to execute several scripts over the same session and be able to commit, or rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If Network DTC Access is enabled, you can use a simple `try/catch` and invoke .NET's TransactionScope object.

```
try {
    $scope = New-Object -TypeName System.Transactions.TransactionScope

    # do stuff
} catch {
    $_.exception.message
} finally {
    $scope.Dispose()
}
```

Calling `Dispose()` on the TransactionScope will either commit or rollback the changes.